# reading a text file word by word and inserting the words in mysql database accordingly

Tags: php, mysql

i have a text file def.txt which looks like :-

Type             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached

Mem:          4039        762       3277          0         59        251

i want to read the file word wise and insert these in mysql database as above format. please help me sort this out.

my current code is :-

```
$fh = fopen('F:\images\def.txt','r') or die($php_errormsg);

for($i=0;$i<=1;$i++)
 {
  if ($s = fgets($fh,1048576)) 
   {
    $words = preg_split('/\s+/',$s,-1,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    $imp = implode(" ",$words);

    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","test") or die("no connection".mysqli_connect_error());
    $a = "insert into test1 values('$imp')";
    if(mysqli_query($con,$a))
        {
            echo "done"."<br>";
        }
    else
        {
            echo "not done".mysqli_error($con)."<br>";
        }
    mysqli_close($con);

}
echo "<br>";
 }
 fclose($fh) or die($php_errormsg);
```

Comment: What is the actual issue with the code you have provided, what is it not doing and what if any error are you getting?

Comment: Could you provide sample of your def.txt ?

Comment: Your loop is 1 iteration long. Is there only 1 line of text in the file? Your query is like "insert into test1 values('123 456 789')". You should loop through the array, not implode, or split the values in the query.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you only use the first line (is that the correct behaviour?), this should do. It takes the numbers and inserts them one by one.

```
$fh = fopen('F:\images\def.txt','r')
    or die('Could not open file');

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","test")
    or die("Could not access database. Error message: ".mysqli_connect_error());

$matches = array();
$line = fgets($fh);
preg_match_all('/\b[0-9]+\b/',$line,$matches);

foreach ( $matches as $word ) {
    $query = "insert into test1 (column_name) values('".
        mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$word)."')";
    if(mysqli_query($con,$query))
    {
        echo "Inserted $word<br/>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Failed to insert $word. Error message: ".mysqli_error($con)."<br/>";
    }
}
```

EDIT: Added [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) for security, although with these numbers it should not be that important. Just good practice.